Finding the “Use Unique Temporary Objects Name” option in the ODI Repository
I would be interested to know how to find (on the ODI Metadata Repository) all Mappings that have this flag enabled on their Physical Design:

“Use Unique Temporary Object Names”
Does anyone know which table I have to query to retrieve this information?

The property you are looking for is SUPPORT_CONCURRENT_EXECUTION in table SNP_MAP_PROP_DEF.
Table SNP_MAP_PROP hold the properties for each mapping.
Something like this could work.
SELECT mp.I_OWNER_MAPPING, m.NAME, mp.NAME, mp.PROP_VALUE
  FROM SNP_MAP_PROP mp JOIN SNP_MAPPING m
    ON mp.I_OWNER_MAPPING = m.I_MAPPING
  WHERE mp.NAME = 'SUPPORT_CONCURRENT_EXECUTION'
    AND mp.PROP_VALUE = 'true';

Alternatively this ODI SDK can be used to retrieve the mapping. The first step would be to loop through all the mapping physical designs, then use the method isConcurrent() of class MapPhysicalDesign.
Note that the documentation for method setConcurrent() gives more context and validates that is concurrency is set, the C$ tables are created with unique names.

Unfortunately this query retrieves no records, despite I'm sure there are multiple Mappings with this property unflagged.  Query doesn't return ANY record even without the second condition (mp.PROP_VALUE = 'true')

By default that property is not selected. If that's the case, that property won't appear in the repository.

Yes it is disabled by default, but I have a few Mappings in my Repository that have this property enabled, and yet they don't appear in the query.
